# Submiting form via javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, forms

```
 function callMethod() {
 document.myForm.submit();}
```

And here's the form:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("MyMethod", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { name = "myForm" }))
           { %>

//bla

<input type="submit" onclick="return callMethod();" value="OK" />
```

And MyMethod is not getting hit. Why is this?

Comment: You're not actually using `jQuery` there .. are you getting an error of any kind?  You probably are..

Comment: What are you trying to do? Removing the whole JavaScript part makes the form get submitted fine.

Comment: @pimvdb Yes but I need JS code in the method to be executed before the form is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
function callMethod() {
    $('#myForm').submit();
}


$('#myForm').submit(function () {
    callMethod();
    return false;
});
```

Or change buttons type from `submit` to `button`, give it an ID and code:

```
$('#buttonID').click(function () {
    callMethod();
});
```

But I actually don't get the sense of what you are doing...

Answer (score 0):

Because submit button already submitted the form. For doing this you have to make a simple button. Not Submit button

Comment: How did it submit when the breakpoint in the method wasn't hit?

Comment: Or prevent default browser behavior, but you need to do this using event and you can't access it if pass your function in `onclick` attribute.

Comment: It submitted because its the form default behavior. To change this default behavior you have to catch the submit event and prevent form from being submit directly.

Comment: @ZahidRiaz But the method didn't run. The lines in the method weren't executed.

Comment: change this line
<input type="submit" onclick="return callMethod();" value="OK" />
use <a href="javascript://" onclick="return callMethod();">OK</a> and Check now the form got submitted or not